# xcodebuild produces different archive to Xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I am using `xcodebuild` to generate an archive from a workspace. I use the following command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme "MyProject" 
           -destination generic/platform=iOS archive 
           -archivePath "../PathToArchive/MyProject.xcarchive
```

(I've spaced it out over multiple lines for readability)

This command generates a `MyProject.xcarchive`. However it generates a *generic* "Xcode Archive" rather than an "iOS App Archive." This cannot be submitted to the App Store.

If I archive the exact same workspace and scheme using Xcode.app version 7.0.1 (7A1001) instead of `xcodebuild` then I get an "iOS App Archive" which can be submitted to the App Store.

Inspecting the contents of these two `xcarchive`s shows the main difference is the bundled `Info.plist` file. The one generated by Xcode.app contains an additional `ApplicationProperties` dict with versioning and signing details. The one generated by `xcodebuild` lacks these details in its Info.plist.

Copying the Xcode.app generated Info.plist into the `xcarchive` generated by `xcodebuild` "fixes" the archive, and it can be submitted to the App Store. This is not a solution however, as it means I cannot build on the command line.

Note that doing `xcodebuild -version` prints:

```
Xcode 7.0.1
Build version 7A1001
```

Edit: *sometimes* `xcodebuild` appears to generate a correct *iOS App Archive* instead of a *Generic Archive*. I'm not exactly sure why this happens. It's not consistent.

Comment: If you upgraded you might need to do a full clean ctrl+alt+cmd+shift+k (i think) and you would need to delete all your derived data

Comment: @Jeef thanks for the advice but a clean and delete of derived data still results in the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of frustration I have discovered the cause of `xcodebuild` producing incorrect `xcarchive` packages.

I had to disable the "Parallelize Build" option for the scheme I was building.

[image: Parallelize Build Setting]

After un-ticking this option, the builds take a lot longer, but `xcodebuild` is consistently producing an "iOS App Archive" rather than a "Generic Archive." With "Parallelize Build" enabled `xcodebuild` would generate a "Generic Archive" 90% of the time, occasionally generating a correct archive.

Because I wanted my build times *within* Xcode to remain unaffected, I left the "Parallelize Build" option enabled for my schemes. I duplicated the schemes to be built with `xcodebuild` and un-ticked the option only for the deployment schemes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Cocoapods? If so try using the pre release version `gem install cocoapods --pre` . I had the issue because of a copy pods phase being somewhere it should not have been, please go through https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4021 you should find a solution that fits you.

Comment: I am using Cocoapods 0.39. Thank you for the link, I will look down that path for a fix. Does this Cocoapods issue only affect `xcodebuild` and not Xcode.app?

Comment: For me it effected both.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've found the cause of the problem and while it was not CocoaPods it was the "Parallelize Build" setting. Which I only thought to try after noticing someone else mention it in the CocoaPods issue tracker.